# Is there a way that I can fix the the errors?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver, automated-tests

I have just started to learn Java and I'm new at using selenium webdriver. I was trying to do a test and run it on Intellij Idea but the following error message appears. I was wondering if there is a way for me to fix it?
I would really appreciate if anyone could help me understand what is going on!

**The error message that appears on console:**

````
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.

   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 91
Current browser version is 106.0.5249.103 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-RT2ML01', ip: '192.168.0.163', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_312'
Driver info: driver.version: Driver
remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
   Ordinal0 [0x010D2DB3+2502067]
   Ordinal0 [0x0106C5B1+2082225]
   Ordinal0 [0x00F72498+1057944]
   Ordinal0 [0x00F905DA+1181146]
   Ordinal0 [0x00F8C43C+1164348]
   Ordinal0 [0x00F89C73+1154163]
   Ordinal0 [0x00FB9A22+1350178]
   Ordinal0 [0x00FB967A+1349242]
   Ordinal0 [0x00FB5BEB+1334251]
   Ordinal0 [0x00F92174+1188212]
   Ordinal0 [0x00F93009+1191945]
   GetHandleVerifier [0x0124EC5C+1511084]
   GetHandleVerifier [0x012F8522+2205554]
   GetHandleVerifier [0x01153393+480739]
   GetHandleVerifier [0x01152579+477129]
   Ordinal0 [0x01071E5D+2104925]
   Ordinal0 [0x010763F8+2122744]
   Ordinal0 [0x01076537+2123063]
   Ordinal0 [0x0107EE53+2158163]
   BaseThreadInitThunk [0x74FBF989+25]
   RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F774B4+228]
   RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F77484+180]


   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$errorHandler$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:62)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$0(HandshakeResponse.java:30)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
   at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
   at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
   at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:486)
   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
   at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
   at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:531)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:128)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
   at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
   at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
   at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
   at internship.driver.DriverFactory.getDriver(DriverFactory.java:20)
   at internship.driver.Driver.start(Driver.java:22)
   at test.MyAccountTest.before(MyAccountTest.java:16)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:134)
   at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:63)
   at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(ConfigInvoker.java:348)
   at org.testng.internal.ConfigInvoker.invokeConfigurations(ConfigInvoker.java:302)
   at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.runConfigMethods(TestInvoker.java:695)
   at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:523)
   at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
   at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
   at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:816)
   at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
   at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
   at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
   at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
   at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:766)
   at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:587)
   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
   at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
   at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
   at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
   at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1187)
   at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1109)
   at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1039)
   at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1007)
   at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
   at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:109) ```
````

Comment: Note: the same general solution applies for most (if not all) Chrome version numbers.  Make sure the Chrome and driver versions match.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your ChromeDriver, because it can't work with your version of Chrome. Choose the most recent version of ChromeDriver or give it an older version of Chrome to use.